Why app display name get truncated on iOS
First question:
I have problem with iOS app display name. I tried many solutions and I read many discussions and I finally managed to add space in CFBundleDisplayName, but I still can't understand why the display name is truncated. I know the app name is 14 chars (including
one space using the following code: &#x2002;), BUT for example Google Translate is 16 chars and I can see the full name displayed. The only information I found is that there is a restriction of 12/13 chars and the width of every character also matters, but I can see only 9 chars of the app name. So any suggestions how can I fix that ?
Second question:
I want to check the app name displayed in the stores both App Store and Google Play. Where can I find and change the app name to become the same as bundle display name ?

XCode version: 15.3
iOS version: 17.4.1


okay, but then how Google Translate is shown ?

Yes, and YouTube Music is 13 chars and the name is fully displayed.
